# Tag not closed error in Datafeed

Tags: 2010, odata

When accessing the standard data feed for a list I get the following error:

Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed IDataReader interface was being used: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: feed. Line 52113, position 13..
The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

Error occurs on a specific list that previously rendered without any errors.

Since then fields of type Yes/no and Choice was added to the list.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: I've then created a list template from the list and included the content and created a new list based on the template. When I access the data feed on the new list, I don't get any errors. Surely this is a bug...